# Getting "cannot verify server identity" on iPhone and iPad for Go Daddy SSL

Tags: security-certificate, iphone, godaddy, safari, ipad

Whenever people navigate to a particular site of ours on an iPhone or iPad they are getting a "cannot verify server identity" message.

Our certificate was issued by Go Daddy.

I ran [this checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=http://www.pariet.com.au) as suggested in another question and everything appears OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was with intermediate certificate. I downloaded a new one from GoDaddy and installed and this has resolved the issue.

Seems there may be a problem with the checker above as it indicated the at the intermediate certificate was OK.

Comment: It's possible that the checker, like desktop browsers, uses the missing intermediate CA as one of its root CAs, which might be why the certificate checked out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but was speaking with someone this morning who mentioned that GoDaddy chain there SSL certificates and that some bits of software don't trust this as they can not look further down the chain.

this article talks about the issue: [SSLShopper cert not trusted](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with a GoDaddy SSL cert not being trusted in iOS on iPad and iPhone. Turns out I didn't install the bundle. After installing the bundle the cert came back trusted and no more cant identify server identity notice in iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on two different servers, meaning if you have apache 2.4.8 or greater use this settings in your config file.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
```

Version's 2.4.7 or less

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
```

Comment: I had the issue with nginx.  In nginx there is not a separate setting for the chain file.  Instead, you have to combine the cert and the chain file into one concatenated file and use it as your cert.  I followed the instructions here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains